# Append a row directly beneath the current row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I use functions like "insertAfter" and "after" although I can add the row directly beneath the row I'm working on, my other buttons on the page cannot "see" this content.  However, when I use "append", it can see the content, but it either adds it to the current row or the bottom of the table.

How do I use append to append directly beneath the row I'm targeting.
Here's a [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bt83afgo/5/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="schedule">
    <tbody id="body">
        <tr class="sun">
            <td>Sunday</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="button" class="add">Add Another</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="button" class="nr">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="mon">
            <td>Monday</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="button" class="add">Add Another</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" name="button" class="nr">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
I see <span id="isee">1</span> of that item

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".add").click(function (e) {
            console.log("add");
            e.preventDefault();
            var thisClass = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
            $tr = $("<tr class='" + thisClass + ">'><td>Hello</td><td>World</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
            // $tr.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
            $tr.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
            var count = $("." + thisClass).length;
            $("#isee").html(count);
        })

        $(".nr").click(function (e) {
            console.log("remove");
            e.preventDefault();
            var thisClass = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
            var count = $("." + thisClass).length;
            $("#isee").html(count);
            $("." + thisClass).each(function (e) {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in you class name.  You have an extra greater than.

```
$tr = $("<tr class='" + thisClass + ">'><td>Hello</td><td>World</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
```

[image: old HTML]

This should be:

```
$tr = $("<tr class='" + thisClass + "'><td>Hello</td><td>World</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
```

```js
    $(".add").click(function(e) {
      console.log("add");
      e.preventDefault();
      var thisClass = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
      $tr = $("<tr class='" + thisClass + "'><td>Hello</td><td>World</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
      // $tr.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
      $tr.insertAfter($(this).closest("tr"));
      var count = $("." + thisClass).length;
      $("#isee").html(count);
    })

    $(".nr").click(function(e) {
      console.log("remove");
      e.preventDefault();
      var thisClass = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
      var count = $("." + thisClass).length;
      $("#isee").html(count);
      $("." + thisClass).each(function(e) {
        $(this).remove();
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="schedule">
  <tbody id="body">
    <tr class="sun">
      <td>Sunday</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="add">Add Another</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="nr">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mon">
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="add">Add Another</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="nr">Remove</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
I see <span id="isee">1</span> of that item
```

Also, in your remove statement, you are counting and updating #isee before you actually remove the items.  This probably wasn't what you meant to do.

Comment: Thank you Jennifer.  I needed another set of eyes on that.  That had been driving me crazy and was just the latest in a series of jquery woes.  You are awesome.